# How to parse hex color code into their respective integer value in flutter

Tags: flutter, colors, hex, color-codes, color-conversion

I'm designing a container and pulling the colorcode from firebase database which is stored as String. Now I want to convert that string(Hex code) into integer(some hex code contains only integer), because Color(0XFFf3234f) take argument as integer only.
***decoration: BoxDecoration(color:Color(ItemList[index].ColorCode)),***, then it is throwing an error ***The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.***
Then I've used:

```
class HexColor extends Color {

  static int _getColorFromHex(String hexColor) {

    hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll("#", "");
    if (hexColor.length == 6) {

    }
    return int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16);
  }

  HexColor(final String hexColor) : super(_getColorFromHex(hexColor));
}
```

This is working fine for colorcode having strings and numbers but it gets failed for color code having numbers only, by throwing following error:
***The method 'toUpperCase' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toUpperCase()***

Then I tried separating numeric values alone but it didn't work at all.

Here are few color codes I'm using:
a74556,827255,a3d57a,662482

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just simply convert ColorCode to int:

```
Color(int.parse('0xff${ItemList[index].ColorCode}'))
```